Calculate $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \sqrt{n^4 + k} \cdot \sin \left( 2\pi \cdot \frac{k}{n} \right) \right) \right) \ $
$$
\mbox{What is the value of this limit ?:}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4} + k\,}\
\sin\left(2\pi\,\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$

I tried looking for sum Riemann sums first, nothing.
I tried to bound the sum and then look for Riemann sums, nothing.
I rewrote the sum making pairs: term $k$ with term
$n - k$ to get the $\sin$ positive.

I am stuck. Can someone help me with this limit ?.

Why do you think it has closed form?

Do you think it is $-1/(4\pi) \approx -0.07957747152$ ?

You're on the right track by making the pairs. Now what can you say about the paired-up terms $(n^4+k)^{1/2} - (n^4+(n-k))^{1/2}$?

@DamianPavlyshyn conjugate them? And then Riemann sums?

As an option, decomposing the square root,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4} + k},\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}=n^2\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac k{2n^2},\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}+o(1/n)$$
$$=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac kn,\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}+o(1/n)\to\frac12\int_0^1x\sin(2\pi x)dx$$

@Svyatoslav: I would literally copy it into an answer 8)

@Svyatoslav. Iteresting (but to complex for this problem) would be to use Lerch function.

The key point is (@Svyatoslav use)
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi k}n=0,\quad \forall n\geq2.}$$
Note that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{n^{4}+k}-n^2\right)\sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right),$$
$$\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^{4}+n}+n^2}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)
\leq\sqrt{n^{4}+k}-n^2
=\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^{4}+k}+n^2}<\frac{k}{2n^2},$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^{4}+n}+n^2}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)
\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)
<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2n^2}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right).$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)}{\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)}=1.$$
Due to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(2\pi x)\ {\rm d}x=-\frac{1}{4\pi}.$$
We can get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{4}+k}\ \sin\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}.$$
